# C - argc changes with operation

Tags: c, function, char, arguments, program-entry-point

for some reason my `argc` argument changes from 4 to 6 if instead of "a+bi + c+di" I write "a+bi * c+di" and I don't know why. What is happening and how can I solve it?

Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define FORMATLOG "Invalid Input. Required format: <a+bi> <operator> <c+di>"
#define INPUTLOG  "Error:  Trying to operate with different sets of numbers"

enum { true, false };

typedef struct {
  double realp, imagp;
} Complex;

int checkIfComplex(char *exp) {

  unsigned int i = 1;

  if(exp[strlen(exp) - 1] == 'i')
    while(exp[i] != '\0') {
      if(exp[i] == '+' || exp[i] == '-')
    return true;
      i++;
    }

  return false;
}

Complex parseComplex(char *exp) {

  Complex number;

  sscanf(exp, "%lf + %lfi", &number.realp, &number.imagp);

  return number;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  printf("%d", argc);

  if(argc != 4) {
    puts(FORMATLOG);
    return false;
  }

  if(argv[2][0] != '%')
    if(checkIfComplex(argv[1]) || checkIfComplex(argv[3])) {
      puts(INPUTLOG);
      return false;
    }

  Complex result,
    fterm = parseComplex(argv[1]),
    sterm = parseComplex(argv[3]);

  switch(argv[2][0]) {
    case '+':
      result.realp = fterm.realp + sterm.realp;
      result.imagp = fterm.imagp + sterm.imagp;
      break;
    case '-':
      result.realp = fterm.realp - sterm.realp;
      result.imagp = fterm.imagp - sterm.imagp;
      break;
    case '*': case 'x':
      result.realp = fterm.realp * sterm.realp;
      result.imagp = fterm.realp * sterm.imagp
               + fterm.imagp * sterm.realp
               - fterm.imagp * sterm.imagp;

    default:
      puts(FORMATLOG);
      return false;
  }

  fprintf(stdout, ">> %g + %gi\n", result.realp, result.imagp);

  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that the '*' is being treated as a wild-card and expanded by the shell before being passed to you application.  For example,

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int ndx;
  printf("%d\n", argc);

  for(ndx = 0; ndx < argc; ndx++)
  {
      printf("argument %d is %s\n", ndx, argv[ndx]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

produces the following output (on a Ubuntu host, using gcc-4.8 as the compiler):

```
******@ubuntu:~/junk$ ./complex a+bi * c+di
6
argument 0 is ./complex
argument 1 is a+bi
argument 2 is complex
argument 3 is complex.c 
argument 4 is complex.c~
argument 5 is c+di
```

I can see two solutions to your problem:

(1) escape the `*` like this:

```
xxxxxx@ubuntu:~/junk$ ./complex a+bi \* c+di
4
argument 0 is ./complex
argument 1 is a+bi
argument 2 is *
argument 3 is c+di
```

Problem here is that you are going to have to escape any symbol that has special significance, and it certainly doesn't seem natural to write *.  Additionally, I'm not sure how portable this is going to be due to shells using different escape charaters.

(2) quote the entire expression like this:

```
xxxxxx@ubuntu:~/junk$ ./complex "a+bi * c+di"
2
argument 0 is ./complex
argument 1 is a+bi * c+di
```

At least here the user can write the expression in a normal form, they just have to remember to quote it.  Additionally, this provides some protection against a user adding an additional space in the expression, vis `a + bi * c+di`.  The problem here is that the use needs to remember to quote the expression and you need to do a bit more parsing to extract the two terms.